# Sitecore Azure deployment failure

Tags: azure, deployment

Has anyone seen this error before? The Azure deployment don't create the database instance on Azure.

```
AMDatabase 'web': Access to SQL Azure service management is unavailable, '
AMDatabase 'master': Access to SQL Azure service management is unavailable
AMDatabase 'core': Access to SQL Azure service management is unavailable, 

11/10/2016, dd:MM:YYYY Staging [S] Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer failed System.ApplicationException: 
Staging [S] Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer failed ---> 
System.ApplicationException: Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer is failed ---> 
Sitecore.Azure.Exceptions.**ManagementApiRequestException**: REST REQUEST FAILED : 
Request: https://management.database.windows.net:8443/DUMMY/services/sqlservers/servers Server response = **40677** 
The operation for the request uri 'https://management.database.windows.net:8443/DUMMY/services/sqlservers/servers' was not found. 
To continue, please provide a valid request uri. 16 1 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Sitecore.Azure.Managers.HttpGatewayManager.GetHttpResponse(String uri, String httpMethod, String versionXMsVersion, String body) --- 
End of inner exception stack trace --- at Sitecore.Azure.Managers.HttpGatewayManager.GetHttpResponse(String uri, String httpMethod, String versionXMsVersion, 
String body) at Sitecore.Azure.Providers.AzureSQL.AzureSqlProvider.CreateDataBaseServer(String subscriptionID, String location, String userID, String password) 
at Sitecore.Azure.Managers.AzureManagers.AzureSqlManager.CreateDataBaseServer(String subscriptionID, AzureSqlDatabase database, String login, String password) 
at Sitecore.Azure.Managers.AzureManagers.AzureSqlManager.CreateDataBaseServer(AzureSqlDatabase azureSqlDatabase, String login, String password) 
at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer.ResolveServer(AzureSqlDatabase azureSqlDb, List`1 resolvedServers, Dictionary`2 preferServer) 
at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer.Action(RolePipelineArgsBase args) at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase args) --- 
End of inner exception stack trace --- --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519)

Comment: I have seen this before. _Something_, I don't know what, causes the Azure Deployment to fail during the SQL Server install. When this occurs, it just stops the deployment of the SQL DB's even though the SQL Server instance is created. In order to fix it, I've had to remove the Azure resources it _did_ create, and do the Azure SQL DB deployment over again. I'll change this to an answer once I get time to format and document appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Azure platform issue. I would check on Azure status portal if they've reported anny issue on the Azure SQL service.

You can also try to deploy Sitecore using different resource group ID (deployment ID). Resource groups, sql servers identifiers are global, even if you remove whole resource group it's still present in the Azure for some time until it will be completely removed. So there might me some problems if you are removing whole resource group or SQL server and right after that you try to deploy using the same ID. But I don't know if that's your case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check the [Microsoft Azure Service Dashboard](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) for any known outages that occurred during the time which the errors were reported by the application.

And as a second suggestion, to check the [firewall rules settings](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/) of your Azure SQL environment by following the steps below

1. Assuming you are connected to the Azure Portal
2. On the default blade, look for SQL Servers
3. On the SQL servers blade, find the server on which you want to check the firewall rules
4. On the Settings blade, click Firewall
5. Check if you need to add a client IP or if the **Allow access to Azure Services** is OFF by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Some checkpoints:
- Is this using the out of box ARM templates from Sitecore?
- Just to make sure, try deploying again in a different resource group with a different resource prefix (deployment id) - if that succeeds, this could potentially be a platform error you're experiencing
- Is this the first time you're executing the template or is this a deployment on top of resources that were already previously deployed?  In the latter case, you'll need to make sure to strip database operations from any Web Deploy packages you're referencing from within the ARM template.